# Sort string lexicographically Python

Tags: python

Say we have a list of strings like this

```
a = ['AA20', 'AB20', 'AC20', 'AD20','B20', 'BA20', 'BB20', 'BC20', 'BD20', 'C20', 'D20', 'E20', 'F20', 'G20', 'H20', 'I20', 'J20', 'K20', 'L20', 'M20', 'N20', 'O20', 'P20', 'Q20', 'R20', 'S20', 'T20', 'U20', 'V20', 'W20', 'X20', 'Y20', 'Z20']
```

I need to sort the list such that the output looks like this,

```
['B20','C20','D20', 'E20', 'F20', 'G20', 'H20','I20', 'J20', 'K20', 'L20', 'M20', 'N20', 'O20', 'P20', 'Q20', 'R20', 'S20', 'T20', 'U20', 'V20', 'W20', 'X20','Y20', 'Z20', 'AA20', 'AB20', 'AC20', 'AD20']
```

My Code

```
print(sorted(a, key=str.lower))
```

How to sort list like the above?

Comment: Aint it sorted by length also?

Comment: The order you want is not actually lexicographic, though. AA20 is lexicographically before B20. If the digits are always going to be the same length, you can sort by length and then lexicographically. Otherwise I'd break up the string into the letters and the digits, and work off of the lengths and lexicographic orderings of each

Comment: wouldn't `print(sorted(a, key=len))` match your output?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :)

```
a = ['AA20', 'AB20', 'AC20', 'AD20','B20', 'BA20', 'BB20', 'BC20', 'BD20', 'C20', 'D20', 'E20', 'F20', 'G20', 'H20', 'I20', 'J20', 'K20', 'L20', 'M20', 'N20', 'O20', 'P20', 'Q20', 'R20', 'S20', 'T20', 'U20', 'V20', 'W20', 'X20', 'Y20', 'Z20']
print(sorted(a, key=len))
```